# Polygonize OS Mastermap. Join by Location QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, ordnance-survey

Our Provider of OS MasterMap data doesn't include filled polygons in the DWG data we buy for projects. I would like to be able to create Polygons of the features.
The Buildings layer works fine (shown in Orange below) as the features are mostly complete. The roads (Blue) don't work as the lines don't complete polygons. If I run **polygonize** on all features I get a nice set of polygons but I lose the layer information which I need for symbology. I have tried using a spatial join (**Join attributes by location**) but I don't think there is a Geometric predicate that works in this case.
Any strategy that might work (other than buying our data from someone else)?
[image: OS MasterMap]